# How to convert ExecuteReader to Json object in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, json.net

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.ExecuteReader();
```

I want to get json object which has "PackageID","PackageNumber","StatusName" from this sqlCommand.How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083709/convert-from-sqldatareader-to-json

Answer (score 0):

You can create an class that has the properties that you required.  E.g.

```
class Package{
    public string PackageID{get;set;}
    public int PackageNumber{get;set;}
    public string StatusName{get;set;}
}
```

Assign this object with reader, then use some JSON library to serialize the object to JSON object.