# Returning JSON from dynamic SQL query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

In my data access layer when I want to serialize something into JSON and give it to the client I've been doing something like

```
 using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetLengthsOfStay", con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        var los = new LOS();
                        los.VisitId = (int)rdr["VisitId"];
                        los.PatientId = (int)rdr["PatientId"];
                        los.Gender = (string)rdr["Gender"];
                        los.Age = (int)rdr["Age"];
                        los.Discharge = (string)rdr["Discharge"];
                        los.LengthOfStay = (int)rdr["LengthOfStay"];
                        losList.Add(los);
                    }
                }
            }
```

There are some instances where I need to query the database with a dynamically generated SQL query, so I don't always know the properties to create a single instance of the object, add it to a list, and return the list.  What's the preferred  method for getting the results from a SQL query back to the client all at one, without using a concrete type using .NET MVC?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov is there not a way to get the results from a data reader or data adapter without using the pattern above?  Something akin to dataReader.DataSource.ToJson()?

Comment: I would rather keep the DAL separate from the UI. You simply return a `List<object>` from your DAL and feed that to a JsonResult in your UI. The JSON serializer will then take care of the rest. By returning directly JSON from the DAL is limiting the usage of this DAL because some other portion of your code that would like to format the results in say XML couldn't anymore reuse your DAL.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov so let's say I have a table with ten columns and using a StringBuilder I concatenate together the columns in the table that a user wants to select (maybe from a client click event).  If I don't know how many columns the user is going to select, I don't know which properties it will have.  How should I deal with not knowing which properties of the database entity the user wants to see?  Should I just ignore the properties they don't select?

Comment: For this purpose an `IDataReader` has an integer property called `FieldCount` and a method called `object GetValue(int i)`. So it would be pretty trivial to combine them to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov that's where I'll start, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16166658/1056259

Comment: @wootscootinboogie the DbDataReader is the lowest level ADO.NET class that ORMs and extension methods use to retrieve data. If you use eg `Dapper` you can run any query and map the results to `dynamic` and serialize the results. eg `var results=cnn.Query<dynamic>("spGetLengthsOfStay",commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Dynamic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// microsoft sqlserver
using System.Data.SqlClient;
// oracle
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace InqdWeb
{
  public class Dbio
  {
    //
    public static class Consts
    {
      public const string msgname = "retmsg";
      public const string valname = "retval";
      public const string jsond = "{ }";
      public const string jsonr = "{ \"" + msgname + "\":  \"OK\" }";
    }
    //
    //
    // »»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»
    // core functions
    // »»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»»
    // 
    //
    //  with  a "sql statement" 
    //    and a connection id, 
    //  prepare the actual sql to get data
    //  return the result as json 
    public static string sqljson
      (string pi_sql
        , string pi_conn
      )
    {
        // empty data
        var vd = Consts.jsond;
        // success message
        var vr = Consts.jsonr;
        string msgout = "00";
        var ld = new List<dynamic>();
        ld = sqlmaster(pi_sql, pi_conn, out msgout);
        //      
        if (msgout.Substring(0, 2) == "00")    // not empty and no errors 
        {
            vd = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ld);
            vr = Consts.jsonr.Replace("OK", "00");
        }
        if (msgout.Substring(0, 2) == "10")    //      empty and no errors 
        {
            vr = Consts.jsonr.Replace("OK", "10");
        }
        if (msgout.Substring(1, 1) == "1")    //      error 
        {
            vd = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ld);
            vr = Consts.jsonr.Replace("OK", msgout);
        }
        // return json with 2 collections: d with data, r with status and message
        var vt = jsonmerge(vd, vr);
        return vt;
    }
    //
    //
    //
    //  with  a sql 
    //    and a conn id
    //  return data as dynamic list
    public static List<dynamic> sqlmaster
      (string pi_sql
        , string pi_conn
        , out string po_msg
      )
    {
        string sql = " ";
        sql = pi_sql;
        // result 
        po_msg = msgout;
        // po_msg     pos1      empty: 1    has rows: 0
        //            pos2      error: >0   no error: 0
        //            pos3...   error message
        return lista;
    }
    //
    //
    //  with    a sql statement 
    //      and a connection string
    //  return the result on a dynamic list
    //  plus a string with
    //        pos1    error         0-ok  1-error
    //        pos2    list empty    0-ok  1-list is empty
    //        pos3... message       return code from non-select  or error message
    public static List<dynamic> sqldo
      (string pi_sql
        , string pi_connstring
        , out string msgout
      )
    {
      // variables
      string sql = pi_sql;
      var lista = new List<dynamic>();
      int retcode;
      msgout = "0";
      // 
      string ConnString = pi_connstring;
      //      
      //
      // 
      // Microsoft SqlServer
      if (SqlFlavor == "Ms")
      {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
          try
          {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            if (sqltype == "R")
            {
              SqlDataReader reada = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              string datatype = "-";
              string colname = "-";
              while (reada.Read())
              {
                var obj = new ExpandoObject();
                var d = obj as IDictionary<String, object>;
                // 
                for (int index = 0; index < reada.FieldCount; index++)
                {
                  datatype = reada.GetDataTypeName(index);
                  colname = reada.GetName(index);
                  bool isnul = reada.IsDBNull(index);
                  if (!isnul)
                  {
                    // add datatypes as needed 
                    switch (datatype)
                    {
                      case "int":
                        d[colname] = reada.GetValue(index);
                        break;
                      case "varchar":
                        d[colname] = reada.GetString(index);
                        break;
                      case "nvarchar":
                        d[colname] = reada.GetString(index);
                        break;
                      case "date":
                        d[colname] = reada.GetDateTime(index);
                        break;
                      default:
                        d[colname] = reada.GetString(index);
                        break;
                    }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    d[colname] = "";
                  }
                }
                lista.Add(obj);
              }
              reada.Close();
            }
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            msgout = "11" + ex.Message.ToString();
          }
        }
      }
      // 
      // Oracle
      if (SqlFlavor == "Oa")
      {
        // Or uses a "
        sql = sql.Replace("[", "\"");
        sql = sql.Replace("]", "\"");
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(ConnString))
        {
          try
          {
            con.Open();
            //
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
              OracleDataReader reada = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              string datatype = "-";
              string colname = "-";
              while (reada.Read())
              {
                var obj = new ExpandoObject();
                var d = obj as IDictionary<String, object>;
                // browse every column
                for (int index = 0; index < reada.FieldCount; index++)
                {
                  datatype = reada.GetDataTypeName(index);
                  colname = reada.GetName(index);
                  bool isnul = reada.IsDBNull(index);
                  if (!isnul)
                  {
                                        // add datatypes as needed 
                    switch (datatype)
                    {
                      case "Decimal":
                        d[colname] = reada.GetValue(index);
                        break;
                      case "Varchar":
                        d[colname] = reada.GetString(index);
                        break;
                      default:
                        d[colname] = reada.GetString(index);
                        break;
                    }
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    d[colname] = "";
                  }
                }
                lista.Add(obj);
              }
              reada.Close();
            // 
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            msgout = "11" + ex.Message.ToString();
          }
        }
      }
      // 
      //
      //
      return lista;
    }
    //
    //
}
```

Use it in your controller

```
string vret = "{'r':{'retval': 'OK' }}";
string sqltxt;
string connt;
connt = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["<your connection>"].ConnectionString;
sqltxt = "<your select>";
vret = Dbio.sqljson(sqltxt, connt, "MsX");  // MsX for MsSqlServer 
return Content(vret, "application/json");
```