# Retrieving data from a database through SqlDataReader and converting it to JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization, sqldatareader

I want to convert my retrieved data into `JSON`; I am using a `SqlDataReader` for retrieving. For that I need to store my data into `var`.
I am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Ambiguous match found.

in the following code:

```
public string GetDetails(int Id)
{   
    var jsonDoc = "";

    string con = "server=FACULTY01\\SQLSERVER2012ENT; database=SampleDb; uid=sa; pwd=sa9";
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(con);
    string qry = "Select * from Information where ID =" + Id;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, scon);
    scon.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    var details = rdr;
    
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    jsonDoc = jss.Serialize(details);
    scon.Close();
    return jsonDoc;
}
```

Comment: Please show the *complete* stack trace. As asides: 1) you should be using `using` statements; 2) you should be using parameterized SQL.

Comment: @JonSkeet dear I am using this as it looks, no more code

Comment: or any other method to stored `reader` into `var` ? I just want to store retried data into `var` for JSON serialization.

Comment: Just because there's no more code doesn't mean there's no more *stack trace*. It's not clear whether your code is even being executed - perhaps this is actually a routing problem? (It's not clear why you've got a `details` variable at all, rather than just calling `jss.Serialize(rdr);` - it's not like using a variable declared using `var` changes anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert from SqlDataReader to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083709/convert-from-sqldatareader-to-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't directly serialize a `SqlDataReader` and expect the output to contain the data from the SQL query.  That's not the way that `SqlDataReader` works.  `SqlDataReader` is a means to retrieve data from the SQL result.  You can use it to populate some other object (such as a `Dictionary<string, object>` or a strongly-typed class you define) which you can then hand to the serializer to produce JSON.

Try the code below instead.  (Also note the use of `using` statements and parameterized SQL in keeping with good coding practices, as mentioned by @Jon Skeet.)

```
public static string GetDetails(int Id)
{
    string con = "server=FACULTY01\\SQLSERVER2012ENT; database=SampleDb; uid=sa; pwd=sa9";
    using (SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(con))
    {
        string qry = "Select * from Information where ID = @id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, scon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);
        scon.Open();

        var details = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows && rdr.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    details.Add(rdr.GetName(i), rdr.IsDBNull(i) ? null : rdr.GetValue(i));
                }
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string jsonDoc = jss.Serialize(details);
        scon.Close();
        return jsonDoc;
    }
}
```

Note that the above code is expecting to get a single row back from the reader.  If you are expecting more than one row then you will need to use another loop and put the resulting data into a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` instead.   Here is the part you would need to change:

```
        ...

        var details = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

        using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        dict.Add(rdr.GetName(i), rdr.IsDBNull(i) ? null : rdr.GetValue(i));
                    }

                    details.Add(dict);
                }
            }
        }

        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop to store the data from the reader. Use a DataTable to store the full table. A single variable will store single column data.

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    var details = rdr["columnName"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this post as it comes first in google search.

Have given an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40632105/4054186) (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083709/convert-from-sqldatareader-to-json/16166658#16166658)):

The requirement is somewhat similar that is of converting sqldatareader result to a json string.

```
public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public async static Task<string> toJSON(this SqlDataReader reader)
        {            
            var results = await reader.GetSerialized();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented);
        }
        public async static Task<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>> GetSerialized(this SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            var results = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            var cols = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                cols.Add(reader.GetName(i));

            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                results.Add(SerializeRow(cols, reader));

            return results;
        }
        private static Dictionary<string, object> SerializeRow(IEnumerable<string> cols,
                                                        SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var col in cols)
                result.Add(col, reader[col]);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Use As  :

```
var result = await reader.GetSerialized(); //to get the result object
```

or

```
string strResult = await reader.toJSON(); //to get the result string
```