# Is there any simple way to populate list model from datareader?

Tags: c#, oracle, model, automapper, datareader

I am getting data by OracleDataReader from table. And I have a model for this table.

Employee Model

```cs
 public class Employee
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int SIRKETID { get; set; }
        public string NAME{ get; set; }
        public string SURNAME{ get; set; }
        public string DEPARTMENT{ get; set; }
        public string STATUS{ get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```cs
 public JsonResult getEmployee()
    {
....
                string sql = @"select * from Employee";
                OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var employee = new Employee();
                    Employee.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                    Employee.SIRKETID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SIRKETID "]);
                    Employee.NAME = reader["NAME"].ToString();
                    Employee.SURNAME = reader["SURNAME"].ToString();
                    Employee.DEPARTMENT = reader["DEPARTMENT"].ToString();
                    Employee.STATUS = reader["STATUS"].ToString();

                    model.Add(Employee);
                }
....
                return Json(new { data = model});
    }
```

This works fine, but I dont want to map columns one by one. I have 100 columns.  And I dont know how much columns in some tables

Is there any simple way to return model as json

Comment: There's a number of MicroORMs (e.g. Dapper). Try to use one of them, if you want to keep SQL queries in code.

Comment: EntityFramework, Dapper, ORMLite, LinQ2Sql: Those proposition are ordered.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use third party library like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), that is a simple object mapper for .Net.

You can check a basic sample of usage below:

```
public class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }    
}

var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("SOME QUERY", new { Name = "DOGNAME" });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the result of your `OracleDataReader` into an arbitrary JSON, you can first serialize it into a dictionary of (string, object), and then convert the dictionary into a json.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16166658/5992860) is an answer on a similar topic which provide some code to do so.

Hope it helps.