# Creating nested JSON with data from SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I am new to .NET and trying to achieve what [shape-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shape-json) does in the Node world.

**Copied from the shape-json npm page:**

Given the following array of objects:

```
var input = [
  {pid: 1, contributor: 'jdalton', projectID: 1, projectName: 'lodash'},
  {pid: 1, contributor: 'jdalton', projectID: 2, projectName: 'docdown'},
  {pid: 1, contributor: 'jdalton', projectID: 3, projectName: 'lodash-cli'},
  {pid: 2, contributor: 'contra',  projectID: 4, projectName: 'gulp'},
  {pid: 3, contributor: 'phated',  projectID: 4, projectName: 'gulp'},
]
```

You can apply a schema like this:

```
var scheme = {
  "$group[contributors](pid)": {
    "id": "pid",
    "name": "contributor",
    "$group[projects](projectID)": {
      "id": "projectID",
      "name": "projectName"
    }
  }
};
```

To get a nested JSON like this:

```
{
  "contributors": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "jdalton",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "lodash"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "docdown"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "lodash-cli"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "contra",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "gulp"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "phated",
      "projects": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "gulp"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my case, I have a product hierarchy (product class -> product subclass -> product) which I am trying to represent as a nested JSON.

**Background:**

- I am getting the data from a MySQL table and reading it into a
  `MySqlDataReader`.
- Following this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083709/convert-from-sqldatareader-to-json), I have been able to serialize
  the data into a JSON

I am clueless on how to create a nested JSON like the example above. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`MySqlDataReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader.htm) implements the [`IDataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatareader?view=netframework-4.8) interface, so we can use a [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) to iterate through its rows and transform them into an appropriate .Net data model.  Then afterwards the data model can be serialized to JSON using [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net).

First, grab the following extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202973) by [Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn):

```
public static class DataReaderExtensions
{
    // Adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1202973
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202935/convert-rows-from-a-data-reader-into-typed-results
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3043/joel-coehoorn
    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectRows<T>(this IDataReader reader, Func<IDataRecord, T> select)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            yield return select(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can generate your required JSON as follows:

```
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var query = reader
        .SelectRows(r => 
                    new
                    {
                        id = r.GetInt64(r.GetOrdinal("pid")),
                        name = r["contributor"].ToString(),
                        project = new {id = r.GetInt64(r.GetOrdinal("projectID")), name = r["projectName"].ToString() },
                    }
                   )
        .GroupBy(r => new { r.id, r.name })
        .Select(g => new { g.Key.id, g.Key.name, projects = g.Select(i => i.project) });

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { contributors = query }, Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Notes:

- I am converting the data reader's rows to a data model comprised of [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) objects, but you could use explicitly typed objects for your final results, if you prefer.
- [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8) is used to group all contributions by contributor id and name.
- [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) is used to project elements of an enumerable into a new form.
- This approach completely skips the intermediate steps of serializing the raw query results to JSON, then parsing and restructuring that initial JSON.
- The `query` itself is lazy so be sure to evaluate it before disposing of the data reader.  In the code above Json.NET actually performs the evaluation during serialization, inside the call to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.
- I wasn't sure whether the `id` columns were 32-bit or 64-bit integers, so I assumed the larger, for safety.
- The code assumes none of the record values are [null](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord.isdbnull?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_IDataRecord_IsDBNull_System_Int32_).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tWxVGF) that mocks up the above using a `DataTable` and `DataTableReader`.

Comment: This is beyond helpful! Thanks a lot.